# How to use Apollo client in getInitialProps? - Next 9.3.5

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-apollo

Using Next 9.3.5 / TypeScript / Apollo boost / [next-with-apollo](https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo)

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(DATA_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    id: someId,
  },
});
```

Does it actually render on the client only? I just checked a page source code, and i saw these data, does it mean that SSR works? Or do i need to use `getInitialProps` and use apollo client there to make a queries, then pass it as props to the component? Also what if i want on the client-side to change queried data on click, should i watch it from the server-side somehow, or just on a client-side?

Comment: Found out anything? Next recommends to switch to `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps` in the newer versions, but there are no examples that are using Apollo.